# Formatting in textareas (especially, how W3Schools does it)

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

**Hello everyone**

I have heard many times that HTML and CSS formatting in the *textarea* tag is **impossible**. But if you take a look at the source code of http://www.w3schools.com , especially their ***try it editor***, you can see that it is just a text area.

*The try it editor:* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image

I did find some *javascript* code that is (**probably**) coloring the text:

```js
function colorcoding() {
    var text = document.getElementById("textareaCode").value;
    text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    text = text.replace(/\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");   
    text = text.replace(/  /g, " &nbsp;");  
    text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
    text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
    text = text.replace(/<br> /g, "<br>&nbsp;");  
    text = w3CodeColorize(text);
    document.getElementById("codecolor").innerHTML = text + "<br>";
}
```

I did try to just copy the CSS, but it did not color the text.

*Could someone explain how the w3colorize function works?*

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: You may see that they are using `w3CodeColorize` in JS [here](http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3codecolor.js)

Comment: who said it's impossible to style a textarea? i've never heard anything like that.

Comment: @MridulKashyap It's not impossible to style a textarea. It's impossible to seperately format the contents within the textarea. You can give it any type of global effect, but nothing specific to the content.

Comment: <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3codecolor.js"></script>  you have to add this script to use the w3CodeColor();

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't format a textarea.

If you look at the html and at the function you just posted, you can see they put the values of the textarea into a div at the end. The div is as follows:

```
<div id="codecolor" class=" codecolorCC"></div>
```

It's located right above the textarea within the html.
As you can see in the css, they use `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` to hide the text in the textarea. This, combined with `background-color: transparent !important;` and turning off the borders makes it 100% transparent. Then what you see is the `<div>` behind it, with the text formatted within spans.

That's how it is.